# Meaning of 'bnds' and dimensions in OCO2 v9 L3 data product

Tags: netcdf, satellite, hdf, terminology, nasa

I cannot seem to understand what, for example, 'lat_bnds' means? Same go for 'lon_bnds', lat/lon_dimensions. These values come from the structurally flat NCDF4, sourced from the [JPL](https://co2.jpl.nasa.gov/build/?dataset=OCO2L2Stdv8&product=FULL) as a custom product.

Reading all available documentation does not hint of any definitions. Here's a visual explanation of my data:

[image: Visual explanation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the [NetCDF Climate and Forecast (CF) Metadata Conventions](http://cfconventions.org/Data/cf-conventions/cf-conventions-1.7/cf-conventions.html#terminology) to get more information about the terminology of the netCDF file:

> - lat_bnds: latitude boundary coordinates
> - lon_bnds: longitude boundary coordinates
> - latitude dimension: A dimension of a netCDF variable that has an associated latitude coordinate variable
> - longitude dimension: A dimension of a netCDF variable that has an associated longitude coordinate variable.
> - time dimension: A dimension of a netCDF variable that has an associated time coordinate variable.

Check the website above for more information.

Comment: Legendary, thanks for the clarification and source for further information!

Comment: @Nathan You are welcome. If the answer solved your problem, please accept it so that it can help others

Comment: Oh yes, whoops. Much appreciated!